# Automorphism that preserves Kahler class

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

The following statement is a Lemma from the paper  "Kahler Manifolds with trivial canonical class" by F. A. Bogomolov:

Let $F:M\mapsto M$ be an automorphism of algebraic manifold $M$, which preserves Kahler class $[w]$ and Volume form $w^n$. Then there exists a Kahler form $w'$, s.t. $[w']=[w]$ and $F^*w'=w'.$

How could we see that the statement is trivial when $M=\mathbb{C}P^n?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one Kahler class on the projective space (up to positive constant muliples); the on of the Fubini-Study metric $\omega$. If $F$ is an automorphism of the projective space, then $\omega' := F^*\omega$ is again a Kahler metric. The hypothesis that $F$ preserves the volume form implies that the Ricci-form of $\omega'$ is equal to the Ricci-form of the Fubini-Study metric. By uniqueness of the Ricci-positive Kahler metric on the projective space, $\omega' = \omega$. Scaling by positive reals then treats the case when we consider a multiple of the Fubini-Study class.

Comment: So I guess the general cases may follow from certain uniqueness of the solution of Ric(w)=certian 1,1-form. Could you give me some reference for this?

Comment: This is maybe nuking a mosquito, but let $r$ be the Ricci-form associated to the volume form $w^n$. By the Calabi conjecture, there exists a unique Kahler metric $w'$ in the cohomology class $[w]$ whose Ricci-form is $r$. Now, $f^*w'$ is another Kahler metric in the same class (by hypothesis), and its Ricci-form is also $r$ (via the volume form). By uniqueness in the Calabi conjecture, $f^* w' = w'$.

Comment: Got it！ Thanks.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon Beautifully explained!